# How do I change the text field to add icon in Laravel Collective?

Tags: html, laravel, forms, laravelcollective

How do you modify laravel collective to include the icons within the text filed?

```
<div class="input-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
       </div>
```

Here is what I've tried

```
{!! Form::number('passing_grade', old('passing_grade'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '80']) !!}<i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
    {!! Form::number('passing_grade', old('passing_grade'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '80']) !!}
</div>
```